# jQuery Validate plugin and Masked Input - ignore not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a field in a form that is not required (there is not rule for it in validate), but I did add masked input to it so that if a user wanted to enter the information it would be in a helpful format.

However, if I click on the field and trigger the masked input, it seems to validate (turns green and gives the "OK").  I tried adding ignore to the validate but it still returns as valid.

Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
$("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999",{placeholder:" "});
$("#jqvForm").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore",
    onkeyup: false,
    highlight: function (label) {
        $(label).closest('.form-element').addClass('error')
            .closest('.form-element').removeClass('success');
        $('#result').html(''); 
    },
    success: function (label) {
        label.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.form-element').addClass('success');
    },
    rules: { etc },
    messages: { etc }
});
```

My input field for SSN does have class="ignore" but "success" is being called which addess the class and the label text.

Comment: How can we answer without seeing the HTML?  Provide enough code for a concise example.  See http://sscce.org

Comment: Also, please fix the grammar and spelling in your very last sentence... as it stands, I don't know what you're trying to say. ~ _"which addess the class and the label text"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unhighlight` callback function is the opposite of `highlight`, not `success`.  And `element, errorClass, validClass` are the only valid arguments for these two callback functions, not `label`.

You also do not have to select `.closest('.form-element')` twice within the same chain; once is enough.  I cannot see your HTML, so I'm not even sure you need this selector in the first place.  I'm assuming `element` is the same as `.closest('.form-element')`, so I removed the latter.  Otherwise, tweak this answer as you wish.

Try this instead...

```
highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass('error').removeClass('success');
    $('#result').html(''); 
},
unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass('error').addClass('success');
},
success: function (label) {
    label.text('OK!').addClass('valid');
},
```

See:  [Callback function documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)

Comment: Thanks Sparky - I was out for a day and just had time to do a Fiddle of it - http://jsfiddle.net/stevelogan/3kNub/  It does seem to be working now but I do want to go through what you posted since my code seems to be working contrary to your hints.